# How to automatically install missing yarn packages?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, webpacker

I'll often run into the following error when starting the server on a Rails project:

```
========================================
  Your Yarn packages are out of date!
  Please run `yarn install --check-files` to update.
========================================
```

Given that the system knows what to do, is there a way to configure Yarn and Rails to automatically perform this action when required (ie: when running `rails server` and there are missing Yarn packages)?

Answer (score 2):

In your `package.json` file, just add an extra command to the script say, "start" that starts your server chaining the `yarn install --check-files` command (reinstall all packages that have changed) and the start command using `&&` like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "yarn install --check-files && someStartCommand someFile.xyz",
  "someOtherScript": "someOtherCommand someOtherFile.xyz",
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can use the `yarn upgrade` command if you want to update your packages  to their latest version based on the version range specified in the `package.json` file by adding an extra command to the script say, "start" that starts your server chaining the `yarn upgrade` command and the start command using `&&` like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "yarn upgrade && someStartCommand someFile.xyz",
  "someOtherScript": "someOtherCommand someOtherFile.xyz",
}
```

You can also add the `--latest` flag to your `yarn upgrade` command if you want to ignore the version range specified in `package.json` and instead install the version specified by the latest tag (potentially upgrading the packages across major versions).

Comment: This is promising, but it doesn't clarify the specifics when invoked with the Rails server start command. I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "specifics" here?

Comment: The missing pacakges notification appears when I invoke the Rails server (ie: `rails server`) - I've started digging into how Rails invokes Yarn so I can make use of your helpful suggestion to use the Yarn scripts, but it doesn't appear that the default Rails config uses the yarn `start` script. (Still investigating)
The Yarn integration with Rails is via https://github.com/rails/webpacker#yarn-integrity

Comment: The "start" script is just a dummy name that I used. You need to check your `pacakge.json` file to find out which script invokes the rails server and chain the yarn command there.

Comment: Instead of installing missing files based on scripts, Is it possible to run the install command as precursor to the integrity check? The webpacker gem runs https://github.com/rails/webpacker#yarn-integrity

Comment: Im not too familiar with webpacker tbh but let me go through the docs and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205625/discussion-between-ivar-and-andrewl64).